# Building SDL2 with NDK toolchain

Tags: android-ndk, build-process, sdl, automake, toolchain

I wonder if anyone did managed to build the fresh SDL2 with the toolchain of the Android NDK(r8d).

SDL2 seems to be very close to the release (since yesterday it isn't "UNDER CONSTROCTION anymore: http://hg.libsdl.org/SDL/rev/0a3d2ec7af6d). It comes with an Android.mk and just compiles fine following the instructions in the bundled README.android file. My question is whether there's really no working automake based build is available or will be available to compile it on Android, or something's wrong with my toolchain setup?

I have installed the NDK toolchain following the instructions of the documentation located at $NDK/doc/STANDALONE-TOOLCHAIN.html. I'm using gcc 4.6. Here's one environment i use:

```
#!/bin/sh
export TOOLCHAIN=$HOME/Android/android-14-arm
export PATH=$TOOLCHAIN/bin:$PATH
export SYSROOT=$TOOLCHAIN/sysroot
export CROSS_COMPILE="arm-linux-androideabi"
export CC=$CROSS_COMPILE-gcc
export CXX=$CROSS_COMPILE-g++
export CPP=$CROSS_COMPILE-cpp
export CFLAGS="-march=armv7-a -mfloat-abi=softfp -mfpu=neon"
export LDFLAGS="-march=armv7-a -Wl,--fix-cortex-a8"
echo "Compiler set up for ARM 14"
```

The configure params:

```
./configure --host=arm-linux-androideabi --prefix=$SYSROOT/usr/local
```

With the same configuration i successfully built libjpeg-turbo v8 and SDL_image.
The configure script recognizes the cross-compiler, and builds the makefile, however, it finds X11 support, can't see the OpenGL ES... The make fails:

```
In file included from /usr/include/features.h:378:0,
             from /usr/include/sys/types.h:27,
             from ./include/SDL_stdinc.h:35,
...
```

I checked the configure log, i have no idea where the "/usr/include" comes from.
But in fact, the generated makefile adds that line in the EXTRA_CFLAGS to the compiler.
The NDK doc refers the --with-sysroot=$SYSROOT as optional, i've included it to see if it solves the problem, but that didn't help.
As a last effort i manually edited the Makefile, fixing that reference, and now the compiler complained about X11.h. 
AFAIK Android has nothing to do with X11, so i guess the whole build-tree completely inappropriate to use with NDK.

I have also tried a different configuration, found in an older thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8973582/building-sdl-for-arm-using-android-standalone-toolchain).
Neither defining -DANDROID -mandroid -fomit-frame-pointer nor changing back to -march=armv7-a -mfloat-abi=softfp -mfpu=vfp -mthumb" solved the problem.

On previous projects, i had to refresh config.guess, and config.sub in order to get my compiler recognized. SDL doesn't seem to use those. Furthermore no Makefile.ac or Makefile.am comes with SDL to work with, and no templates for other platform could be used for a good starting point to create my own makefile. Additionally, i've never had to deal with makefiles, i really have no chance to sort out these problems. Even if it succeeds, i will probably need a configure tool as well, since i have no idea how ndk-build manages to install SDL2 without configure scripts.

Compiling the SDL sources with the project together is the only working - but ugly solution. I would like to deploy the necessary lib and header files by make install.

I hope the solution is something really easy and obvious thing that i just didn't think about...

Comment: The error snippet isn't really the error. You've missed putting in the error, and all that's in there is the file containing the error.

Comment: Building SDL2 using configure;make should work in theory, but none of the devs buiild it like that, that's the reason why it's bugged. Feel free to report any bugs you find (and patches!) to Bugzilla https://bugzilla.libsdl.org

One thing you can try, if you feel like experimenting, is running configure, after that copy include/SDL_config_android.h on top of SDL_config.h, then run make, perhaps that works (SDL_config_android.h is a pre cooked config header for Android which should have sane settings).

Answer (score 2):

This issue has been fixed at http://hg.libsdl.org/SDL/rev/4e57cfd9fca8 and expected for the 2.0.4 release. Note there are newer revisions with some related fixes about defines.